# Reducing a fraction with exponents

Tags: fractions

How do I reduce

$$
    \frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2}
    $$

to simplest terms? My algebra is really rusty...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about $$\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2} = \left(\frac {k+1}{k}\right)^2$$
since $\;\dfrac{a^n}{b^n} = \left(\dfrac ab\right)^n$

That's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Needs another TU +1

Answer (score 1):

That fraction is already in simplest terms, since $k$ and $k+1$ don't share any common factors.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2}$=$\frac{k^2+2k+1}{k^2}$=$1+\frac{2}{k}+\frac{1}{k^2}$

Comment: Oops I fixed it.

Comment: Brilliant. That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Observe that if integer $d$ divides both $k+1$ and $k,$

$ d$ will divide $(k+1-k)=1\implies (k+1,k)=1$

Now, $(a^n,b^n)=(a,b)^n$